# $\mathbb{Z}^2$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translation is 'separable'

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, geometric-topology

I have to study the following G-Action $$ \begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\ (m,n)\times (x,y) & \longmapsto (x+m,y+n) \end{cases} $$
That is, as the title says, the Group $G=\mathbb{Z}^2$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translation.

I managed to show the following property of the $G$-Action

> i) $\forall x \in X ,\exists U \ni x$ neighborhood : $gU \cap U \neq \emptyset \implies g=e$

I also have to verify the property

> ii) If $x,x' \in X$ are not in the same $G$-orbit, then $\exists U \ni x, U' \ni x'$ neighborhoods : $gU \cap U' =\emptyset , \ \forall g \in G$

---

I am stuck with showing ii)

**My approach**: Let $x=(x_1,x_2), x'=(x_1',x_2') \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x \neq g x'$ where $g=(g_1,g_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. That is $x,x' \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are not in the same $G$-Orbit.

Now let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $U:=B_\epsilon (x)$ and $U':=B_\epsilon (x')$ the open balls around $x,x'$

My goal is to show that they are disjoint for all elements of $g \in G$.

The only possible way I can think of is producing a contradiction by assuming that there exists an element lets call it $g'=(g_1',g_2') \in G$ such that $g'U \cap U' \neq \emptyset$ $$ \implies \exists z \in g'U \cap U'  \implies z=(u_1',u_2')=(g_1'+u_1, g_2' + u_2) \\ \implies u':=(u_1',u_2')=g'u$$

Where  $u_1,u_2 \in U, \ u_1',u_2' \in U$

Therefore the elements $u=(u_1,u_2)$ and $u'=(u_1',u_2')$ are in the same $G$-Orbit. I am not sure if this helps me in any regard, I fail to see a contradiction because my backbone on $G$-actions isn't strong enough yet.

How can I continue?

If all of it is wrong, how can I show ii)?

**Edit**: We call property ii) that the action is **separable**

Comment: **Hint** What does it mean in terms of the values of $x$, $x'$ for those points to be in different $G$-orbits? (Also, your choice of $\epsilon$ will have to depend on the values of $x, x'$.)

Comment: @Travis, if I understand your question right, then I have already written that in the above $$x \neq gx' \iff (x_1,x_2) \neq (g_1+ x_1', g_2+x_2') $$, I just didn't spell it out. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What is the fundamental domain of this action? You will see that property (ii) is nothing else than the question to separate two distinct points in a square which is rather trivial. (draw a picture ["in your mind"] it will make everything obvious)

Comment: @Spaced Yes, that's the meaning of $x \neq g x'$ in terms of the components of $x, x'$ *for a particular $g$*. How can one test (for this particular action) whether a given $x, x'$ are in the same $G$-orbit, i.e., how can we determine whether there is *some* $g$ for which $x = g x$?

Comment: @Travis, it seems to me like you're asking me for an universal method on how to do so, I would only know of 1  method which is to find such a $g$ manually by hand. But you're talking about deciding whether or not such an element exists, which sounds like a Proposition/Theorem to me. I am afraid I do not know that.

Edit: However I do know that the elements $x=gx$ are fixpoint elements, denoted by $X^G$ so I suppose you want me to show that $X^G \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Spaced I actually mean a characterization *specific to this particular group action*: If $x, x' \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ are in the same $G$-orbit, what can we say about the components of $g, g'$?

Comment: So if $x=gx' \iff g_1=x_1-x_1', g_2=x_2-x_2'$ where the respective indices denote the  entries of the components $x$ and $g$.

Comment: You say "let $\epsilon>0$" without specifying any value. Your proof therefore cannot possibly succeed, because you have not ruled out the possibility that $\epsilon = 2d(x,x')$, and the conclusion is false in that case. The only possible route to a proof is to write down a particular value of $\epsilon$ dependent on $x$ and $x'$, and to prove the conclusion for **that** value of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score -1):

You must to see  what's happening on the  fundamental domain what is the unit square.